# UserPrincipal.Current returns app pool service account

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am using windows authentication on local IIS. `UserPrincipal.Current` returns app pool service account. `User.Identity.Name` returns null.

Here is the web config:

```
    <system.web>
       <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
       <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
       </authorization>
       <identity impersonate="false" />
    </system.web>
```

I tried using `impersonate = true` as well, but it didn't help.

[image: Only windows authentication enabled in IIS]